# What wallet should I use to collect the mining payout from multiple machines?

Tags: wallet, mining-pools, miner-configuration, mining-reward

I am trying to set up my Debian Server so that I can join a mining pool.

I already know that I am going to use `cgminer` for the mining software because it will work with the server format (command line).

What I am not sure about is what type of wallet I should use and how I would link multiple machines to one wallet (I want to use my home computer as well).

Comment: Please be aware that unless you have free electricity, mining with anything but ASIC hardware has become unprofitable. You might want to read the following question before continuing: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1452/5406

Comment: The title and the content of this question didn't match at all. The title had lured 5500 views already most likely only for visitors to find out that it has nothing to do with what they were were looking for. I've therefore edited the title to better align with the content of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what wallet you use, it's entirely unrelated to your mining except as a payout. The address you withdraw to can be in a wallet anywhere (even offline).

P.S. You should really consider upgrading to [BFGMiner](http://bfgminer.com) instead.

Comment: thanks.  but why BFGMiner instead?

Comment: BFGMiner is much more stable, uses standard Linux drivers, a more informative text-user-interface (TUI), has better GBT support (including solo mining), support for more devices, etc...

Comment: I ended up using that.  But I cannot get it to recognize any of my server's devices.  The server is a Dell PowerEdge R200 and it has an AMD ATI ES1000 embedded card but BFGMiner can't find it and I don't know why. Could it be a problem with drivers or OpenCL?

Comment: Probably, but note that mere GPUs and CPUs can only emulate real mining devices, and will *cost* you money to run, not make any.

Answer (score 0):

An online wallet would work well. I know this question is old but I thought I'd try for a more current answer.

The reason I suggest online wallet, is because you can access it from any computer, browser, smart device, etc.

[CoinBase](https://coinbase.com) is a great option because you can buy and sell Bitcoin, Ethereum, and Litecoin... so if you mine it and want it in USD ASAP set your miner up with a CoinBase wallet.

Another online wallet is the [Blockchain.info's](https://blockchain.info/wallet/#/) wallet.

These both are great wallets I use and trust, and they also have great mobile applications.

If you'd like to trade your bitcoin on an exchange, I'd recommend either opening a CoinBase/GDAX account (they are linked so if you have money in your CoinBase wallet you can transfer with no fees to the GDAX exchange)

or [Bitfinex](https://www.bitfinex.com/), which currently is the largest volume Bitcoin exchange out there.

Be warned though, I suggest you use exchange wallets for short term, many large exchanges have been hacked in the past, the best example would be [MT. Gox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mt._Gox)

If you want to play it safe and have the actual wallet on your computer, just download [BitcoinCore](https://bitcoin.org/en/download) on to your favorite/most accessible/secure computer. However, you have to download the Blockchain, which takes a bit, but is worth the time and storage for some.

Happy Bitcoining